# Apache2 isn't serving index.php

Tags: php, apache

My server is fairly old (based on SuSE 9), and while I try to go through the pain of updating to the latest Apache2, PHP5 and MySQL, I ran into this problem with one of my hosted domains.

The site has an index.php, and if I browse to their site example.org/index.php it displays fine.

But if I navigate to http://example.org or http://example.org/ , Firefox pops up a dialog asking if I want to save the file or view it in a program.  The downloaded file is a copy of the unprocessed index.php file.

The config file for the domain has not changed, but clearly I messed up something.  In the config file is "DirectoryIndex index.php".  In the DocumentRoot is a .htaccess file with only "XBitHack on".

Confusing the matter is that I have another hosted domain with a Wordpress install that also uses index.php, and navigating there works just fine.

Here's the site:  http://www.sjbridge.org   or http://www.sjbridge.org/index.php

Mojo

Here's some more information:  When I navigate to http://www.sjbridge.org, Firefox presents the file as "application/x-httpd-php" in the content-type, but for /index.php the content-type is, of course, text/html.

Comment: Could it be it's sending the wrong headers? What does your httpd.conf say ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, I cleared the cache in my browser and the problem went away. Let me say "Never mind."